# Does Konik already support ZugFERD 2.1 which includes XRechnung as a choosable schema?

Tags: zugferd

Since XRechnung will become mandatory in Germany for many governmental customers of companies, the use of Konik would be great to simplify software development across all existing e-invoicing standards in Germany. Does it already - or when will it support XRechnung/ZugFERD 2.1x?

Comment: Referring to https://konik.io/ (could'nt add that tag)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, Konik does not support ZugFERD 2.1 yet.

However, Mustang does. Note that I'm the author of [mustangproject](https://www.mustangproject.org).

I keep a list of open source projects on https://zugferd.github.io/.

Comment: How does the validation with a given x-rechnung xml work? Regarding to the kosit page, there is no single xsd to validate a xml rather than schematrons etc.

Comment: You can download the schema files (=XSDs) for the UN/CEFACT CII part of EN16931 from https://unece.org/trade/uncefact/xml-schemas (the 2016b uncoupled version) or better, because limited to the european subset, as part of the ZUGFeRD Infopaket (the EN16931 profile). This is a good start but the schematron files add important additional checks, they are usually applied by converting them to XSLT. I tried to summarize the architecture of the validation module of Mustang on  https://github.com/ZUGFeRD/mustangproject/blob/master/doc/ZUV-Architektur.svg